# Polynomial greatest common divisor over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

> Find the $\gcd$ of the polynomials $f(x)=5x^3 + x^2 + 5x + 1$ and $g(x)=5x^2 + 21x + 4$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

For now I get these results

- $f(x)=g(x) x + (x+1)$
- $g(x)=(x+1)(5x+1) + 3$

But I'm stuck in the last passage and I think I've gone wrong somewhere in the exercise.

Comment: What you denote $\mathbf{Z(5)}$ is the field with $5$ elements $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$?

Comment: @Bernard I hope so, because that's what I assumed when I edited the question.

Comment: Over $Z_5$ is $5x^3 == 5x^2==0 $ The polynomials are $x^2+1$ and $ x-1$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: In this case, there's a problem with coefficients…

Comment: Yes I mean the field with 5 elements , sorry for my notation

Comment: @Davide Then that $21$ is a bit strange.

Comment: @Davide Note that polynomials over $\mathbb Z_5$ have coefficients in $\mathbb Z_5$, and $21$ would reduce to $1$ in $\mathbb Z_5$ after taking remainder. The fact that you have not made this reduction is the confusing part : did you know that you can do this reduction (and therefore, $g(x) = x+4$ over $\mathbb Z_5$, for example) or did you prefer to stick to the original question?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I made the reduction in the reminder but I wasn't sure if I could make the reduction already in the beginning. This is a new argument for me and I'm trying to understand better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.The reason why you can reduce the coefficients of a polynomial modulo $p$ if evaluating the gcd of two or more polynomials modulo $p$, is because the $\gcd$ makes sense only for polynomials in the same ring : you cannot interpret $p$ and $q$ as polynomials with integer coefficients and demand their $\gcd$ over $\mathbb Z_5$, because they are not polynomials over $\mathbb Z_5$, but rather real polynomials. If they appear to have real, and not $\mathbb Z_p$ coeffients,then we reduce each coefficient modulo the prime to get a polynomial of simpler representation, which is equivalent to this polynomial in the ring of polynomials over $\mathbb Z_p$.

That is , $f(x) = x^2+1$ over $\mathbb Z_5$ and $g(x) = x+4=x-1$ over $\mathbb Z_5$. So the $\gcd$ of $f$ and $g$, *as polynomials over $\mathbb Z_5$*, is $1$, because $g(x)$ is irreducible (every polynomial of degree $1$ is)  and does not divide $x^2 + 1$ because $1^2 + 1$ is not equal to $0$ modulo $5$, so $g(x)$ is not a multiple of $f(x)$. Therefore, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are coprime in $\mathbb Z_5$.

Comment: It would also help to notice that $x^2+1=x^2-4=(x+2)(x-2)$ factors into linear factors, and $x+4=x-1$ is not among them.

Comment: Ah, yes. That also helps.